# How to have code activated when viewing a image on discord?

Tags: discord, png, jpeg

I want to try to make code behind a image when it is viewed on discord like  those image loggers and learn about how dangerous image files are.Im not sure if 1 click methods like those claimed are real so I want to test it out for myself but I'm not sure how to start

I have no idea how to start the code.